# Dataframe value replacement

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, databricks, rdd

I am trying to replace 'yyyy-MM' with 'yyyy-MM'+'-01' below is my code and I am not getting it right. Note, I am working on databricks:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat, lit, when


# Show the DataFrame
new_df.show(5)

from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat, lit, when

# Create new columns with replaced values
new_df = clinicaltrial_df.withColumn(
    'Start_new',
    when(
        col('Start').contains('-'),
        col('Start')
    ).otherwise(
        concat(col('Start'), lit('-01'))
    )
).withColumn(
    'Complete_new',
    when(
        col('Completion').contains('-'),
        col('Completion')
    ).otherwise(
        concat(col('Completion'), lit('-01'))
    )
)

# Show the DataFrame
new_df.show(5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is aimed at appending `'-01'` to values in the `Start` and `Completion` columns of a DataFrame
if they do not already contain a '-'. However, it seems you want to specifically target strings formatted
as `'yyyy-MM'` and ensure they become `'yyyy-MM-01'`.
To achieve this, you need to identify strings that precisely match the `'yyyy-MM'` format.

You could use the [`regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html)
function from PySpark's `sql.functions` module.
This function can search for a regular expression pattern and
replace matching parts of the string with a specified replacement string.
For your case, you can look for strings that match the pattern of a year and month (`'yyyy-MM'`)
**and do not end with a day.**
Then, append `'-01'` to these strings to standardize them as full dates (`'yyyy-MM-01'`).

Here's how you can adjust your code:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace

# Adjust the DataFrame
new_df = clinicaltrial_df.withColumn(
    'Start_new',
    regexp_replace('Start', r'^(\d{4}-\d{2})$', concat(col('Start'), lit('-01')))
).withColumn(
    'Complete_new',
    regexp_replace('Completion', r'^(\d{4}-\d{2})$', concat(col('Completion'), lit('-01')))
)

# Show the modified DataFrame
new_df.show(5)
```

The approach shown above ensures that only strings formatted exactly as `'yyyy-MM'` are altered,
accurately targeting the described requirement and leveraging the powerful pattern matching capabilities
of regular expressions to implement the desired transformation.

#### Example

Here's an example of the above solution for some dummy data:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, col, concat, lit, when
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

# Initialize SparkSession (not necessary if you're running this in Databricks as it's already initialized)
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()

# Define schema for the DataFrame
schema = StructType([
    StructField("ID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Start", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Completion", StringType(), True)
])

# Sample data
data = [
    ("001", "2022-01", "2022-12-31"),
    ("002", "2022-05-01", "2023-05"),
    ("003", "2023", "2023-11"),
    ("004", "2022-07", "2022-09-15")
]

# Create DataFrame
clinicaltrial_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)

# Showing original DataFrame
clinicaltrial_df.show()
# +---+----------+----------+
# | ID|     Start|Completion|
# +---+----------+----------+
# |001|   2022-01|2022-12-31|
# |002|2022-05-01|   2023-05|
# |003|      2023|   2023-11|
# |004|   2022-07|2022-09-15|
# +---+----------+----------+

# Apply the solution
new_df = clinicaltrial_df.withColumn(
    'Start_new',
    regexp_replace('Start', r'^(\d{4}-\d{2})$', concat(col('Start'), lit('-01')))
).withColumn(
    'Complete_new',
    regexp_replace('Completion', r'^(\d{4}-\d{2})$', concat(col('Completion'), lit('-01')))
)

# Show the modified DataFrame
new_df.show(truncate=False)
# +---+----------+----------+----------+------------+
# |ID |Start     |Completion|Start_new |Complete_new|
# +---+----------+----------+----------+------------+
# |001|2022-01   |2022-12-31|2022-01-01|2022-12-31  |
# |002|2022-05-01|2023-05   |2022-05-01|2023-05-01  |
# |003|2023      |2023-11   |2023      |2023-11-01  |
# |004|2022-07   |2022-09-15|2022-07-01|2022-09-15  |
# +---+----------+----------+----------+------------+
```

**Note:** the dates only get appended if both the year and month are present on the string
in that respective order. If you also have dates that only contain the year (`'YYYY'`),
dates that have orderings of year/month other than `'YYYY-MM'`, or dates that do not use
`'-'` as year/month separator (e.g., `'YYYY/MM'`), these values will remain unmodified.

#### Regex pattern breakdown

If you're not familiar with regex string patterns, here's a breakdown of the pattern being
used in the code above:

- `regexp_replace` is used with a regular expression pattern `r'^(\d{4}-\d{2})$'`:

  - `^` asserts the start of the string.
  - `(\d{4}-\d{2})` matches and captures a group consisting of four digits (representing the year),
    followed by a hyphen, and then two digits (representing the month).
  - `$` asserts the end of the string.

Comment: Please note that if your answer is generated using generative AI it violates the [Stack Overflow AI policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy).

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, your answer resolved my issue